# Problems with if - elif passing a list from a Options-Menu

Tags: python, reference

I have a problem and haven't found a solution yet :(

I want to have a main database from which I can do some evaluation.

Please have a look at this code :

```
def main():
    # Hauptmenue
    screen() # Options-Screen
    choice = ask_choice() # simple input routine
    if choice == "l": # load database
        mftemp = laden() # load database into mftemp
        print("********MF-Gesamt im Main********") # just to check if 
        for i in range(len(mftemp)):               # datase is present
            print(mftemp)
        print("********Laden-Fertig***********")
        mfgesamt = mftemp # see comment (1)
    elif choice == "h": # I want to do some calculation here
        print("MF-Gesamt-Hilfe")
        mfgesamt2 = hilfe(mfgesamt) # Error, see comment (2)
        for i in range(len(mfgesamt2)):
            print(mfgesamt2)
    elif choice == "q":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Auswahl nicht vorhanden")
    print("********Main*ein**********") # see comment (3)
    for i in range(len(mftemp)):
        print(mftemp)
    print("********Main*aus**********")
    mfgesamt = mftemp
    main()
```

What I want to do :
Type "l" and load database
type "h" and do some calculation on the loaded database

Comment (1) : the database is loaded well, mfgesamt and mftemp are displaying the wanted content.

comment (2) : Error : local variable 'mfgesamt' referenced before assignment
I tried many iterations with the variables, put them into the routine, put them into main and so on. Nothing worked

comment (3) : after loading, the data is displayed well, like in comment (1)

If you please can give me some hint or advice where to look and get rid of this error.
It seems to me, that starting the main-routine again will erase the variables.
But I don't have an idea how to fix it. (Goto will be helpful :)

My programming experience is a bit "rusty", some Basic from C128 and Acorn-Basic :)

Thank you very much for your help.
AndreWas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a loop instead of recursion, then your variables remain intact

```
def main():
    while True:
        # Hauptmenue
        screen() # Options-Screen
        choice = ask_choice() # simple input routine
        if choice == "l": # load database
            mftemp = laden() # load database into mftemp
            print("********MF-Gesamt im Main********") # just to check if 
            for i in range(len(mftemp)):               # datase is present
                print(mftemp)
            print("********Laden-Fertig***********")
            mfgesamt = mftemp # see comment (1)
        elif choice == "h": # I want to do some calculation here
            print("MF-Gesamt-Hilfe")
            mfgesamt2 = hilfe(mfgesamt) # Error, see comment (2)
            for i in range(len(mfgesamt2)):
            print(mfgesamt2)
        elif choice == "q":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Auswahl nicht vorhanden")
            print("********Main*ein**********") # see comment (3)
            for i in range(len(mftemp)):
                print(mftemp)
            print("********Main*aus**********")
            mfgesamt = mftemp
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply ! I've done your suggestions and have also put the loading routine into main :) It works fine.

Comment: Then you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)